# Proving there's a function $f$ such that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=l \Rightarrow \lim_{x\to 0}f(\sin x)=l$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

> Prove that there's a function $f: (-a,a)\setminus\{ 0 \}$ such that if $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=l$ then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}f(\sin x)=l$

Well, the answer is simply the constant function $f(x)=c , \ \forall c\in\mathbb R$, do I prove it by contraposition: assume there's no such function then try the constant function thus getting a contradiction ?

Comment: Since $\sin x \sim x$, actually it's true for any function that has a limit at $0$.

Comment: Is $(-a,a)\setminus\{0\}$ the domain of $f$?

Comment: identity maybe ?

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By triangle inequality $$\left|f(\sin x)-l\right|\le |f(\sin x)-f(x)|+|f(x)-l|$$ Now, let $f$ be a Lipschitz continuous function on $(-a,a)\setminus\{0\}$ with constant $L>0$. Then, $$|f(\sin x)-l|\le L|\sin x-x|+|f(x)-l|$$ Now, $\forall\epsilon >0$, one can now choose $\delta, \eta_1>0, \eta_2>0$ such that $\delta L\eta_1+\eta_2<\epsilon$ so that $$|f(\sin x)-l|\le L|x|\left|\frac{\sin x}{x}-1\right|+|f(x)-l|\le L\delta\eta_1+\eta_2<\epsilon$$ Hence $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(\sin x)=l$

Comment: A fine and correct solution, no doubt. However, for a question that says "show that there exists and $f$...", direct demonstration of an $f$ that works (e.g. $f(x)=x$, $f(x)=c$, etc.) is a much more straightforward route, IMO.

Comment: Yes, I know, that's true. I was just trying to show that one can find a large class of such functions.

Comment: You can take a larger class: $f$ does not need to be lipschitzian, or even continuous. You just need a limit at $0$.

Comment: Yes, correct @Jean-ClaudeArbaut. The statement is very general.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the question, the answer consists in any (explicit) function with the desired properties. You can answer $f(x)=x$ for $x \in (-a,a) \setminus \{0\}$ and *prove* that it has the desired property. This is very easy.

Comment: Wouldn't it be even easier to prove for the constant function ?

Comment: It's even easier for constant functions