# Given a function $f\in(-a,a)\smallsetminus\{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$. Prove that if $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=L$ then $\lim_{x\to 0}f({\sin(x))=L}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Given a function $f\in(-a,a)\smallsetminus\{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$. I want to prove that if $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=L$ then $\lim_{x\to 0}f({\sin(x))=L}$.

I was trying to prove it using Cauchy's definition but got stuck along the way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: There is no logical connection in your question's first part. Perhaps you mistyped something. Check again carefully your question...

Comment: I fixed everything. My apologies

Comment: It is still not true; a counterexample would be $a=1$, $f(x)=x+1$, and $L=1$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784985/proving-theres-a-function-f-such-that-lim-x-to-0fx-l-rightarrow-lim?rq=1

Comment: @MyGlasses I have seen this thread but they don't prove the general case there

Comment: This is nothing but substitution in limits. You can use the more general result described in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1073047/72031).

Answer (score 2):

Take any $\;\epsilon>0\;$, then

$$\begin{cases}
I\;\;\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)=L\implies \exists\,\delta_1>0\,\,s.t.\,\, |x|<\delta_1\implies|f(x)-L|<\epsilon\\{}\\
II\;\;\lim\limits_{x\to0}\sin x=0\implies \exists\delta_2>0\,\,s.t.\,\,|x|<\delta_2\implies |\sin x|<\delta_1\end{cases}$$

Define now $\;\delta:=\min(\delta_1,\,\delta_2)\;$ , then

$$|x|<\delta\stackrel{II}\implies |\sin x|<\delta_1\stackrel I\implies |f(\sin x)-L|<\epsilon$$

Comment: BTW, no need of that $\delta\;$ there. It is enough to take $\;|x|<\delta_2\;$ and we're done.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Take $\delta>0$ such that$$|x|<\delta\implies\bigl|f(x)-L\bigr|<\varepsilon.$$Then $|x|<\delta\implies\bigl|\sin(x)\bigr|<\delta$, because$$(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}):\bigl|\sin(x)\bigr|\leqslant|x|,$$and therefore$$|x|<\delta\implies\bigl|f\bigl(\sin(x)\bigr)-L\bigr|<\varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 0):

For any sequence $x_n\neq 0$ such that $x_n\to 0$ we have $f(x_n) \to L$. That is just the assumption reformulated.

Take $x_n=\sin(y_n) $ such that $y_n \in(-\pi, \pi)\setminus \{0\} $ and $y_n\to 0$. This $y_n$ is arbitrary enough for this setting (why? $\star$). We have  $x_n\to 0$ by the continuity of $\sin(\cdot) $. And so $f(\sin(y_n)) =f(x_n)\to L$. Since $y_n$ was arbitrary we have:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(\sin(x))=L$$

---

$(\star) $ The answer for "why?"

Take  an arbitrary $z_n\neq 0$ such that $z_n\to 0$. There exist $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$ we have $z_n\in (-\pi, \pi) \setminus \{0\} $. For the limit it is enough to consider $y_{n} =z_{N+n} $.  So $y_n$ is arbitrary enough.

Comment: Well, $\;y_n\;$ isn't *that* arbitrary as you chose them from $\;(-\pi,\pi)\setminus\{0\}\;$ (who knows why, btw...)

Comment: @DonAntonio take  $z_n\neq 0$ such that $z_n\to 0$. There exist $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$ we have $z_n\in (-\pi, \pi) \setminus \{0\} $. For the limit it is enough to consider $y_{n} =z_{N+n} $.  And that is why I said so. Now you agree?

Comment: Oh, I think I know what you tried to do...but  perhaps it is worthwhile to edit your answer and add a little word about this.

Comment: @DonAntonio done that! Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

Let t=sin(x). If x approaches 0 then t approaches 0, therefore f(t)=f(sin(x)) approaches L.